# Media Queries wont work?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, bootstrap-modal

So I have researched extensively on this site about Media Queries not working and I am still having trouble. The margin changes will not show up at all even though I put in,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Here is an example of something simple I am trying to do,

```
<div class="modal-content">
 /*Content of modal is here*/
</div>
```

and here is the css followed by media query:

```
.modal-content{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .modal-content {
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left: -40px;
        width: 300px;
     }
}
```

I need to give the modal margin so it will look center on an iphone 5 but it won't read my media query at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you are reaching the width of `320px`?

Comment: After I cleared my caches my css started to work. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

to target iphone 5 use below media query for your code

```
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    // your code
}
```

here you can learn more about it https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thank you! Actually once I cleared my Caches everything started to work -___- keep it simple stupid as they say. I'll make the post as solved.